# Количество разных чисел в массиве c++

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть целочисленный массив, как найти количество разных чисел в нем? Собственно, как функцию сравнения (проверку) правильно задать, вот эту: `if ((arr[i]!=arr[i-1]))`, чтоб считало нормально.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int N;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "vvedite kolichestvo elem ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "vvedite massiv:" << endl;
    int arr[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        if ((arr[i] != arr[ i - 1 ]))
        {
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "kolichestvo raznih" << count << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так а что вы ожидаете получить, сравнивая только соседние элементы в неупорядоченном массиве? То есть просто заданием такой "сравнялки" вы задачу никак не решите. Надо предпринимать более серьезные шаги.

Comment: я пробовал добавить j, для прохода и сравнения, но не получилось.

Comment: @Awesome Man  Помимо j есть еще k, l, m, n. А что делают переменные a и b?

Comment: @Awesome Man  Никогда еще такого веселого поста по C++ не встречал.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow,ничего, я просто изменял старый код,забыл убрать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А так нельзя

```
std::unorered_set<int> s;
std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::inserter(s, s.begin()));
std::cout << "kolichestvo raznih" << s.size() << std::endl;
```

?

Или

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
int count = std::unique(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr)) - std::begin(arr);
std::cout << "kolichestvo raznih" << count << std::endl;
```

?

Если уж совсем "в лоб" решать, то, например, так

```
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  int j;
  for (j = i + 1; j < N && arr[j] != arr[i]; ++j);
  count += j == N;      
}

std::cout << "kolichestvo raznih" << count << std::endl;
```

Это, конечно, неинтересное решение, но зато цикл `for` с пустым телом удалось применить :)

---

Вообще-то

```
int N;
...
int arr[N];
```

в С++ не допускается.

Comment: можете написать через цикл,или иначе,попроще. Я просто, новичек, мне ваш метод пока не доступен.Спасибо!

Comment: `int arr[N];`,нас так учили. `count += j == N; `,что ето  означает? к count плюсуется j, и приравнивается к N?

Answer (score 2):

Раз речь пошла о циклах, то я вам покажу, как надо писать циклы!:)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    const size_t N = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);

    size_t count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        while (j < i && a[j] != a[i]) ++j;

        count += j == i;
    }

    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}
```

Или более содержательная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 20;
    int a[N];

    std::srand((unsigned int)std::time(nullptr));

    for ( int &x : a ) x = std::rand() % N;

    for (int x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    size_t count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        while (j < i && a[j] != a[i]) ++j;

        count += j == i;
    }

    std::cout << "There are " << count << " unique elements" << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть, к примеру, следующим образом

```
10 17 12 15 5 1 17 19 0 6 13 5 4 13 6 4 18 10 5 11
There are 13 unique elements
```

Comment: `std::`,зачем ето? не проще ли,написать `using namespace std;`?Спасибо!

Comment: @AwesomeMan Нет, не проще. Это может привести к коллизии имен. Например, переменная с именем count может конфликтовать со стандартным алгоритмом с тем же самым именем count.

Comment: `count += j == i;` , что происходит в етой строчке кода?

Comment: @AwesomeMan Значение выражение j == I либо true либо false, которое приводится к целочисленному значению либо 1 либо 0. Если совпадений не найдено, то значение будет true, то есть 1, которая будет прибавлена к переменной count.